# Passing an object to a method

Tags: java, object, methods

quick question.

I'm trying to create a showroom for vehicles.  These vehicles are bought by customers.

I'm having a problem with my BuyVehicle method and passing a Customer object to it.  Is this possible? if so, how would I go about it?

My code is below:

Customer class:

```
public class Customer {

final String custName;
private String custContact;



public Customer(String a, String b){

custName = a;
custContact = b;


}
```

My TestCustomer class

```
 public class TestCustomer {

 {



    Customer c1 = new Customer("Thomas Brown", "tb@email.com");


      {

         System.out.println("Customer Details: " + c1.toString());



      }
   }
}
```

I've created a vehicle using the constructor in my vehicle class, but I need to know how to pass the above customer to my BuyVehicle method as seen below:

BuyVehicle method

```
public void buyVehicle( String a, Customer c1) { // buy method for the vehicle
dateSold = a;
custName = c1.custName;
sold = true;
```

The line i'm struggling with:

```
v1.buyVehicle("021113", );
```

v1 is the vehicle, the string is the date sold but I need to add the customer name into the arguments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then why don't you pass it?

Comment: The vehicle shouldn't know how is sell, instead use another class that has this responsability to sell a vehicle to a customer

Comment: Why are you showing us the `TestCustomer` when the problem is with the `Vehicle` class.  Do you have a seperate `TestVehicle`? Otherwise, you're not calling the `Vehicle` method anywhere in your `TestCustomer`

Comment: I really suggest you post all of your code. Also, you `TestCustomer` class, based off the code above, look totally ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
v1.buyVehicle("021113", c1);
```

Im sure I am missing something but lets hear.

Comment: Could it be because i'm creating the object in another class?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just this?

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("a", "b");
Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(....);
v1.buyVehicle( "date", c1);
```

Comment: Correct ;) but really bad design in my opinion ( just answering the question he asks I know )

Answer (score 0):

```
public void buyVehicle( String a, Customer c1) { // buy method for the vehicle
    dateSold = a;
    custName = c1.custName;
    sold = true;
```

This line `custName = c1.custName` is saying that `Vehicle` has a `custName`

```
public class Vehicle {
    String custName;
}
```

Does it? If not, put it in there. Note: If a `Vehicle` does have a `custName`, that's very poor class design

As far as your `TestCustomer`, first of all, you have no `main` method

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't be easier to create 3 classes: customer, vehicle, transaction.
create the customers and vehicles in the transaction class, and link them together with buyVehicle(Customer c,Vehicle v, String date) ?